# Detect if PC power is on/off then turn a TV on/off using an Arduino

Tags: power-supply, arduino, atx, pc

I'm building an arcade cabinet using an old PC and an old(ish) Bush LCD TV as the monitor. The TV is connected to the PC graphics card via HDMI and all is good. However, the problem is that I want the TV to turn on/off when the PC (arcade machine) turns on/off. Currently the TV just stays on with a 'No Signal' message when the PC shuts down, and conversely, stays off when the PC is powered on — both not ideal.

I've managed to solder 2 wires to the physical TV on/off button and when I touch the 2 wires together the TV turns on/off — so far so good. But now I need a clever way to wire this up to an Arduino and program the Arduino to "touch" the wires together when it detects that the PC is powered on/off.

Is there a simple way to detect if a PC is currently on/off? I'm thinking I need to tap in to the ATX power supply and "listen" for certain voltages? Or am I over complicating the problem? Any suggestions are more than welcome! Thank you.

Comment: Wifi smart switch. Have the pc run a script when it turns on and turns off to turn the lcd on/off.

Comment: Alternatively yes, you could sense if the 5V atx supply is on (not 5VSB standby).

Comment: @Passerby thank you for the suggestions. Would you mind providing a few more details on how I would implement either of these ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Simplest would be to drive a relay with the PC's ATX supply...

Comment: I was thinking about a similar thing recently: Turning off the external devices when the PC is turned off, but realising this without opening up the case and modifying anything. The easiest(!!!) solution I could think of was to use a tiny light sensor to sense the POWER ON LED and control the externals with relays accordingly: If the LED is off then the PC is off, so disconnect everything from grid :)

Comment: you can buy a powerbar that turns on peripherals when the PC is turned on and turns peripherals off when the PC is turned off

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful ideas. I'm going to look into using/detecting the 5V "power on" and see if that works. I might also explore using a hall sensor; this could maybe detect the magnetic field if I place it on one of the ATX wires or main PC power cable? I'll report back soon.